# native element is cannot access correctly in in angular 5

Tags: angular, jspdf

I have a problem like this. I am making report generation part in angular 5 using jsPdf. This is my component.html file part.

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div id="content">
      <h1>My First PDF</h1>
      <p>Hello Welcome To Easy Lab Reservation System</p>
    </div>
    <button (click)="downloadPdf()" class="btn btn-info">Create Report</button>
  </div>
```

This my component.ts file.

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import * as JSPDF from 'jspdf';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  templateUrl: './report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.css']
})
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  downloadPdf(){
    const doc = new JSPDF();
    let specialElementHandlers = {
      '#editor' : function(elemnt, renderer){
        return true;
      }
    };

    let content = this.content.nativeElement;

    doc.fromHTML(content.innerHtml,10,10,{
        'width': 190,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers

    });
    doc.save('MyFirst.pdf');


  }

}
```

When I hit on Create report button. It gives me an error like this.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
    at ReportComponent.downloadPdf (report.component.ts:26)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ReportComponent.html:113)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13589)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14685)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:10004)
    at eval (core.js:10629)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (platform-browser.js:2628)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
```

I search lots of time to find out a solution to this problem. But Those were not enough to full fill my requirement. Can someone help me solve this issue with my code?. And I want to get to know

```
let specialElementHandlers = {
          '#editor' : function(elemnt, renderer){
            return true;
          }
        };
```

what this code part do in here?

Thank You!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `<div id="content">` to  `<div #content>` .